# Generating a random "maze" -- 3d Array C++

Tags: c++, maze

so I'm working on a school assignement, as I'm learning C++. I'm not so much looking for code to be given to me as help understanding/coming up with the right algorithm for this problem.

I need to create a (5x5x5) 3d maze of 1's and 0's. Populate it randomly (except 0,0,0 being a 1 for start and 4,4,4 being a 1 at the finish.

Here's what I've done.
I made a cube object:

```
#include "cube.h"
Cube :: Cube(int cube_value)
{
    cube_value = 0;
    chk_up = false;
    chk_down = false;
    chk_left = false;
    chk_right = false;
    chk_front = false;
    chk_back = false;
}
Cube :: ~Cube(void){}
```

in my maze managing class I initialize like this

```
PathFinder::PathFinder()
{
    // initializing / sizing 5x5x5 Maze
Maze.resize(5);
    for(int y = 0; y < 5 ; ++y)
    {
        Maze[y].resize(5);
        for(int z = 0; z<5 ; ++z)
        {
            Maze[y][z].resize(5);
        }
    }

    int at_x = 0;
    int at_y = 0;
    int at_z = 0;
}
```

The header for that class:
    #include "PathfinderInterface.h"
    #include "cube.h"

```
class PathFinder : public PathfinderInterface {
private:
    int at_x;
    int at_y;
    int at_z;
public:
    vector<vector<vector<Cube> > > Maze;

    PathFinder();
    virtual ~PathFinder();

    string getMaze();

    void createRandomMaze();

    bool importMaze(string file_name);

    vector<string> solveMaze();
};
```

So I'm trying to populate it and this is what I have, it might not make a ton of sense:

```
void PathFinder :: fillmaze()
{
    Maze[0][0][0].cube_value = 1;
    Maze[4][4][4].cube_value = 1;
    int atx = 0 , aty = 0 , atz = 0;
    while(atx<5 && aty < 5 && atz < 5)
    {

        if(atz == 5)
        {
            aty = aty + 1;
        }
        if(aty == 5)
        {
            atx = atx + 1;
            atx = 0;
        }

        for(atz=0 ; atz<5 ; ++atz)
        {
            if((atx!= 0 && aty!=0 && atz!=0) || (atx!=4 && aty!=4 && atz!= 4) )
            {
                Maze[atx][aty][atz].cube_value = (rand() % 2);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm attempting to fill all the z axis and trace to the right on x, then move up one y and do the same, is this a good approach, or is there a better way of doing this? I'm just getting pretty confused.

Comment: is there a reason it has to go in one point, and come out the other?

Comment: Did you read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_generation_algorithm ?

Comment: EvilT - The assumption is that the maze will start at one end and on the other, so there needs to be a valid number for the path at those points. n0rd - I have not seen that, thanks for the reference I will look into that.

Answer (score 1):

```
void PathFinder :: fillmaze()
{
    int atx = 0 , aty = 0 , atz = 0;
    while(atz<=4)
    {
    if(atx == 5)
    {
        aty = aty + 1;
    }
    if(aty == 5)
    {
        aty = 0;
        atz = atz + 1;
    }
    if(atz < 5)
    {

            for(atx=0 ; atx<5 ; ++atx)
            {
                     Maze[atx][aty][atz].cube_value = (rand() % 2);
            }

    }
    }
         Maze[0][0][0].cube_value = 1;
         Maze[4][4][4].cube_value = 1;

 }
```

This worked! Now on to maze traversal! :/